# Reading from file at eof

Tags: fortran

When reading from a file using the following command, and get iostat value to be eof, is the data from s valid or should I discard it?

```
Read (u, "(a)", iostat=st)  s
```

Comment: No , means the data in `s` is invalid and I should not use it?

Comment: Correct, sorry if that's unclear. Data in a read statement that failed has an undefined value. So the data is invalid. I'm certain it's true in your case (eof), and I think it's true for any read that didn't return success. If nobody else has a better answer (or a link to duplicate) I'll add an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Note that the end of file and end of record conditions are not error conditions.  The question linked to in the comments above refers to error conditions.  Data may still be returned from a read statement that encounters an end of record condition.

Comment: As a suggestion for the question: could you add the two(?) lines showing how you determine it's EOF?

Comment: The supposed duplicate is actually talking about error conditions, not end of file.  Aspects of the behaviour under error conditions and end of file are similar, but not that they are not the same things - details differ.

Comment: @IanH Agreed: I've voted to reopen.  That other question could be modified to ask about end-of-file also, but at the moment it doesn't cover the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon an end of file condition for a READ statement, all variables in the input list become undefined.  See F2008 9.11.3 item (3).